# How to split a string within an iteration in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to split an string within an iteration. **As example**:

```
10||A||##||20||B||
```

In the end I need the values within each delimeters, e.g. `10, A` etc.
But my result is `1,0,A`
What am I missing here? Thx!

```
String[] rows = values.split("##");
String[] tmp;
for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   tmp = rows[i].split("||");
   stQuantityManuell = tmp[0];
   stLager = tmp[1];
   stPlatz = tmp[2];
}
```

Comment: `tmp = rows[i].split("\\|\\|");`. This has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
rows[i].split("\\|\\|");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below code

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;  
class StringFormatExample
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("10||A||##||20||B||","||");  

         while (st.hasMoreTokens()) 
        {  
            System.out.println(st.nextToken());  
            }  
    }
}
```